# using c# to create node in drupal

Tags: c#, web-services, drupal, xml-rpc

i need to make a ("webservice") c# app that can create/update/delete nodes for/from drupal 7 using xmlrpc. everytime i run my app i get errors from the xmlrpc files(library). I tried to find code/documentation for C# using xmlrpc to connect to drupal, but in vain. 
I would be nice if you could point me in the right direction, or share some c# code with me.

```
{
[XmlRpcUrl("http://testing/testserver")]
public interface IDrupalServices
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("node.get")]
    XmlRpcStruct NodeLoad(int nid, string[] field);
    [XmlRpcMethod("node.save")]
    void NodeSave(XmlRpcStruct node);
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IDrupalServices drupal = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IDrupalServices>();

        int nid = 227;
        string[] fields = new string[] { };

        XmlRpcStruct node = drupal.NodeLoad(nid, fields);

        string teaser = node["teaser"].ToString();
        welcomeTxt.Text = teaser;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string title = txtTitle.Text;
        string body = txtBody.Text;

        IDrupalServices drupal = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IDrupalServices>();

        XmlRpcStruct node = new XmlRpcStruct();

        node["id"] = 1001;
        node["title"] = title;
        node["body"] = body;
        node["teaser"] = body;
        node["format"] = 1;
        node["type"] = "webservice";
        node["promote"] = false;

        drupal.NodeSave(node);
        MessageBox.Show("The post was been created!");

    }
}
}
```

After i run this i get the error: Server returned a fault exception: [-32601] Server error. Requested method node.get not specified.  - in the XmlRpcSerializer.cs

Thank you,
Florin

Comment: Please post sample code you've tried, and the actual error message you get. Check out http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Drupal 7 you must be using Services 3 which doesn't have a `node.get` method (or `node.save` as it happens). They've been replaced with `node.retrieve` and `node.create` & `node.update` respectively.

You can view all of the available methods in the `resources/node_resource.inc` file in the Services module folder.

**UPDATE**

Internally the node is submitted using `drupal_execute` which is the function used to submit a form. Since the body is a field in Drupal it's expected to be a multi-dimensional array in this format (PHP version):

```
$data["body"][$language][0]["value"]
```

The `$language` will either be the specific language for the node, or `und` for undefined language (unless you're dealing with a multi-lingual site `und` is usually the way to go). You'd need to build an array similar to that in your C# code and Drupal should save it.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

The [Java XML-RPC client example for Services](http://drupal.org/node/1267522) uses a `HashMap` type to do this so my best guess is you could use a `Dictionary` (albeit one that seems unnecessarily complicated):

```
var innerValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
innerValue.Add("value", txtBody.Text);

var language = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();
language.Add(0, innerValue);

var body = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
body.Add("und", language);

node["body"] = body;
```

It's been a few years since I've coded in C# so forgive any errors in there. Also I'm pretty sure it could be declared more efficiently but I've forgotten most of the language to be honest!

Comment: thank you, that worked.. but still i have a problem with the body of the node, if i add text  to the node["body"] it won't appear. Can u tell me why?

Comment: @pretender: It's to do with the way Drupal expects fields on a node to be formatted (the body being a field in Drupal 7). I've updated the answer, hope it helps

Comment: i made an array [,,] but in vain. Could you share some code, if it's not too much to ask. i'll owe you one. thanks!

Comment: @pretender: I've had another go :)

Comment: thanks for the code:D the app runs but when i hit the button to create the node it gives and error in the XmlRpcStruct.cs                                   ---       System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]] cannot be mapped to an XML-RPC type

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! i managed to make it. Instead of dictionary i used XmlRpcStruct. works like a charm

Comment: Good stuff glad you got it sorted

Comment: Clive can u tell me how can i retrieve body from a specific node? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Jan's answer is not quite right. If you are using the cook xmlrpc library all you would need to do is this:

```
        XmlRpcStruct postStruct = new XmlRpcStruct();
        postStruct.Add("type", "article");
        postStruct.Add("title", "wohoo another test");

        XmlRpcStruct postBodyStructParams = new XmlRpcStruct();
        postBodyStructParams.Add("value", "My body yaaay");
        postBodyStructParams.Add("format", "filtered_html");

        XmlRpcStruct[] postBodyStructParamsArr = new XmlRpcStruct[1];
        postBodyStructParamsArr[0] = postBodyStructParams;

        XmlRpcStruct postBodyStruct = new XmlRpcStruct();
        postBodyStruct.Add("und", postBodyStructParamsArr);

        postStruct.Add("body", postBodyStruct);
```

Unfortunately, the body params need to be an array of struct under the `"und"` key with only one value. I blame this on the sloppiness of the drupal xmlrpc API.